# Android app bugs/errors only on certain phones

Tags: android, debugging

I've released an app about a month ago now, and it works as it should on my Desire and presumably on a lot of other phones. However it is also receiving it's fair share of 1 star ratings with comments that say that the sound simply doesn't work. Given that this is an app to play sounds and alarms that's a pretty major problem.

Thankfully one user emailed me to say it didn't work for her, so I at least know one model of phone it's not working on. However I have ZERO idea how you would even begin to work out why code isn't working on a particular phone. If the code is written as per the android docs, and it works in the emulator and on my own phone, I can't begin to work out where to start fixing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: "If the code is written right" - that's a big assumption :) perhaps post the smallest snippet of code that shows how you play your sounds.

Comment: I meant 'written as per the android docs', edited to clarify this.

Comment: Got it. One other thing to try - what Android version are you running on your emulator? If not 1.5 or 1.6, perhaps it's worth making an AVD for one of those and firing that up.

Comment: I have a similar problem, my app works on every phone/simulator except HTC EVO 4G. Now, I don't have access to this device, how can I test my app for this phone? I see no other way except looking for online emulators like DeviceAnyWhere! Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are contacted by a reasonably advanced user, they could either install a logcat app such as *aLogcat* or access logcat output over USB if they have the SDK installed, and mail you the output of the phone logs after running your app. It might have some hint as to what is failing.

Comment: Thanks for the logcat app tip. I've emailed the only person to contact me about it and hope she's able.